# How to drop the one's place digit in an integer

Tags: python

```
num = 123
num_shrunk = "for example"(num)
print(num_shrunk)
120

num = 93
num_shrunk = "for example"(num)
print(num_shrunk)
90
```

I want to remove the place value of one in integer (I don't know the word to explain it).

Comment: I guess the proper term to explain it is "rounding to multiple of 10".

Answer (score 3):

You definitely don't need NumPy, you can get away with just using integer division.  You use `//` to divide without a remainder and multiply by 10 to get that place value back:

```
n = 123   
new_n = (n // 10) * 10 

print(new_n)
```

> 120

If there is a possibility the number will be negative and you want the same ability, you'll have to negate it, do the process above, and multiply it by -1 to get the correct number.

```
n = -93

if n > 0:
    new_n = (n // 10) * 10
else:
    new_n = (-n // 10) * -10
```

> -90

Answer (score 3):

In addition to previews answers, you can subtract num with remainder:

```
num_shrunk = num - num % 10
```

, where num % 10 computes the remainder of num divided by 10.

Edited according to comments from @jonsca

If num could be negative numbers, then

```
if num > 0:
    num_shrunk = num - num % 10
else:
    num_shrunk = num + num % -10
```

Answer (score 1):

**Another option** *Edited according to the comments from @ack and @wovano*

1. Convert the integer to string
2. Remove the last character from the string
3. Append a `0` to the string
4. Convert the string back to integer

**Code**

```
num = 123
num_shrunk = int(str(num)[:-1] + '0')
print(num_shrunk)
```

**Print**

> 120